# jquery width increase/decrease with scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to increase and decrease the width of a div when i scroll the page . I am able to increase the width of the div from right after i scroll down 150px , but the div width is not decreasing when i scroll before 50px as i coded that .

Code for increase

```
var scroll_pos = 0;
jQuery(document).scroll(function() {
    scroll_pos = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (scroll_pos > 100) {
        scroll_pos = 100;

    }   
    jQuery(".roadway-sec-1").animate({
        width : (0+1*scroll_pos)+"%"
    });         


});
```

Code for decrease

```
jQuery(document).scroll(function() {
    var current=jQuery(".roadway-sec-1").width();
    scroll_pos = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (scroll_pos < 50) {
        scroll_pos = 50;

    }   
    jQuery(".roadway-sec-1").animate({
       width : "-=50"+"%"
    });         


});
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just do the trick in one function?

```
jQuery(document).scroll(function() {
    scroll_pos = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (scroll_pos < 100 && scroll_pos > 50) {
        jQuery(".roadway-sec-1").animate({
            width : scroll_pos+"%"
        });
    }   
});
```

Comment: I thought of this and tried now but it does not reaches the full 100% and then it reaches different width even after scrolling the whole page down but not 100% and width decrease does not works

Comment: Can you provide a JSFiddle? So i can see the problem

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the code inside the same `jQuery.scroll()` event handler rather than in two separate handles.

Or this could be a CSS styling error.

Comment: Emm the increase one works perfectly . I don't think so . I am not able to just figure out the decrease once

Answer (score 0):

I finally put in some logics and this one worked . Its better to share it :)

```
var scroll_pos = 0;

jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
    scroll_pos = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (jQuery(window).scrollTop() < 50) {
        scroll_pos = 0-0*scroll_pos;

    }
    else
    {
        scroll_pos = 0+2.0*scroll_pos;
    }
    jQuery(".roadway-sec-1").width(scroll_pos);

    });
```